# Sequence Does not Reset after Completion

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I am trying to accomplish a "slideshow" function that can be reused for different elements. I am testing it on a div containing paragraph text from my HTML document, represented as *container1, container2*, and *container3*. Clicky() is called on onclick="" on a button.

```
let slideshow_divs = ["container1", "container2", "container3"];
    for(let i = 1; i < slideshow_divs.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(slideshow_divs[i]).style.display = "none";
}

let current_view = 0

function clicky() {
    document.getElementById(slideshow_divs[current_view]).style.display = "none";

    current_view = current_view + 1
    document.getElementById(slideshow_divs[current_view]).style.display = "block";
}
```

After container3, container1 and container2 are set to display:none; When passing container3, and returning to container1, it remains display:none; So the sequence ultimately only works once.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a modulo operator to wrap around to the beginning of your array again:

```
current_view = (current_view + 1) % slideshow_divs.length;
```

To illustrate, here's a table of the progression of the `current_view` value with and without the modulo operator:

```
Without modulo          With modulo
--------------          -----------
      0                      0
      1                      1
      2                      2
      3 (OOB)                0
      4 (OOB)                1
      5 (OOB)                2
```

Without modulo, you will go outside of the array bounds (OOB) once `current_view` hits 3.

Comment: That worked - quick and easy. Thank you for your help. I'll mark your answer correct as soon as the cooldown has depleted :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a method for resetting the `current_view` count back to `0` when you've reached the total number of slides. This can be done with modulo or a simple `if` conditional on the `.length` of `slideshow_divs`:

```
let slideshow_divs = ["container1", "container2", "container3"];
    for(let i = 1; i < slideshow_divs.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(slideshow_divs[i]).style.display = "none";
}

let current_view = 0;

function clicky() {
    document.getElementById(slideshow_divs[current_view]).style.display = "none";

    if (current_view < slideshow_divs.length) {
        current_view = current_view + 1;
    } else {
        current_view = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById(slideshow_divs[current_view]).style.display = "block";
}
```